# Calling a WCF service via native C++

Tags: wcf, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

What is the best way to call a WebService via C++ ??

I want to avoid to use a C# Wrapper DLL with a COM Interface, so is there a Native way without using Sockets? In my current project the interface is trivial, but if there would be also a proxy generation it would be definitely the better choice :-)

Comment: [I've done your job for you](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=soap+c%2B%2B).

Comment: i googled myself and already tried a few ways. there must be some hidden gem, or we can bury c++

Comment: Probably http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430435(v=vs.85).aspx but it's Vista and later. If you want XP you can try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztta389h(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: the Web Services API i havent tried yet, this sounds like a good solution. thx

Comment: I say it's Vista and later which isn't 100% true. But for most intents and purposes it's Vista and later, [XP has some special licensing scheme](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2009/10/09/final-version-of-windows-web-services-api-for-windows-xp-vista-server-2003-and-server-2008-is-now-available.aspx).